# how to compile my Java source files

Tags: java

I'm really new to this JAVA RMI project.
I just wonder what compiler can I use to compile my JAVA source code?
And how to do it?

- I'm trying to compile example source code from http://www.eg.bucknell.edu/~cs379/DistributedSystems/rmi_tut.html

Thanks!!!

Comment: Err, the Java compiler? Whats the question here?

Comment: I'm not sure the correct term for the 'compiler' that can run my java source code.

Comment: There is nothing that can 'run' your source code. You compile your source code, with a compiler, in this case `javac`, then you run the resulting *object code* with the `java` command. None of this has anything to do with RMI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to do javac, there is no special requirement. Refer this [link.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/example.html)